# Analog of mysql_real_escape_string (PHP+MySQL) for Lua Nginx Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, nginx, lua

What is analog of function
`mysql_real_escape_string` (and backward function) in Lua postgresql?
I want do achieve some sequrity and usability features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three escaping functions provided in [Lua for PostgreSQL](https://github.com/mbalmer/luapgsql): `escape`, `escapeLiteral` and `escapeIdentifier`, which you can use based on your specific needs.

Mind switching to prepared statements, though. In that case you do not have to worry for special characters in query arguments, as they are processed and passed separately. That's the most secure and robust way.